# Entity Framework Column with values from 2 tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

For simplicity, I have a database with this tables

```
Toys
- Id
- Name
Fruits
- Id
- name
Orders
- Id
- Product (contains Fruits.Id or Toys.Id)
- Type (1 if Fruit, 2 if Toy,....)
- Qty
```

¿how can I map "Product" to store id´s from 2 entities (Fruits or Toys)?

PD: The Id of toys and fruits never match

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a hard requirement then I would do it by making a view in the database called Products, and it would be a union between Toys and Fruits.

But notice that the navigational property Product, on orders then will be of type Product, and you have to map it to Fruit or Toy manually.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Maybe if add a new column to Orders named "Type" can be easy?
this columns contains, for example, 1 for toys, 2 for fruits, etc.
But how can i tell EF this ?